# Multiple line plots on a single graph with presentation delay

Tags: python, pandas, plot, figure

With apologies if I have missed a correct prior answer, I have searched dozens of similar inquiries for what I think is a simple answer.  I am not a qualified programmer but have hacked my way through a wide variety of data collection and presentation solutions. I am trying to plot a large collection of data imported from an instrument output .csv.  Visualizing the change in data is the reason for the plot, it is important to me to present the data at a user-controlled rate (e.g., with plt.pause()).  Here is a simplified version of what I have now:

data = [{'Channel_No':0, 'Value1': 0, 'Value2': 0, 'Value3': 0, 'Value4': 0, 'Value5': 0},
{'Channel_No':1, 'Value1': 2, 'Value2': 1, 'Value3': 3, 'Value4': 4, 'Value5': 5},
{'Channel_No':2, 'Value1': 4, 'Value2': 2, 'Value3': 6, 'Value4': 8, 'Value5': 10},
{'Channel_No':3, 'Value1': 6, 'Value2': 3, 'Value3': 9, 'Value4': 12, 'Value5': 15},
{'Channel_No':4, 'Value1': 8, 'Value2': 4, 'Value3': 12, 'Value4': 16, 'Value5': 20},
{'Channel_No':5, 'Value1': 10, 'Value2': 5, 'Value3': 15, 'Value4': 20, 'Value5': 25},
{'Channel_No':6, 'Value1': 8, 'Value2': 4, 'Value3': 12, 'Value4': 16, 'Value5': 20},
{'Channel_No':7, 'Value1': 6, 'Value2': 3, 'Value3': 9, 'Value4': 12, 'Value5': 15},
{'Channel_No':8, 'Value1': 4, 'Value2': 2, 'Value3': 6, 'Value4': 8, 'Value5': 10},
{'Channel_No':9, 'Value1': 2, 'Value2': 1, 'Value3': 3, 'Value4': 4, 'Value5': 5},
{'Channel_No':10, 'Value1': 0, 'Value2': 0, 'Value3': 0, 'Value4': 0, 'Value5': 0}]

df=pd.DataFrame(data)

df.plot(x=0)

with successful output:

[simple chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yX9T2.png)

But this is all created together.  How do I plot column 1 ('Value 1'), wait 10 seconds, and plot column 2 ('Value 2'), and so on, without re-creating the figure? I can do this the hard way (trimming the data and plotting in a loop) but that is pretty hard on the eyes because every line addition invokes a plot refresh. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work in your case:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from celluloid import Camera

data = [{'Channel_No':0, 'Value1': 0, 'Value2': 0, 'Value3': 0, 'Value4': 0, 'Value5': 0}, {'Channel_No':1, 'Value1': 2, 'Value2': 1, 'Value3': 3, 'Value4': 4, 'Value5': 5}, {'Channel_No':2, 'Value1': 4, 'Value2': 2, 'Value3': 6, 'Value4': 8, 'Value5': 10}, {'Channel_No':3, 'Value1': 6, 'Value2': 3, 'Value3': 9, 'Value4': 12, 'Value5': 15}, {'Channel_No':4, 'Value1': 8, 'Value2': 4, 'Value3': 12, 'Value4': 16, 'Value5': 20}, {'Channel_No':5, 'Value1': 10, 'Value2': 5, 'Value3': 15, 'Value4': 20, 'Value5': 25}, {'Channel_No':6, 'Value1': 8, 'Value2': 4, 'Value3': 12, 'Value4': 16, 'Value5': 20}, {'Channel_No':7, 'Value1': 6, 'Value2': 3, 'Value3': 9, 'Value4': 12, 'Value5': 15}, {'Channel_No':8, 'Value1': 4, 'Value2': 2, 'Value3': 6, 'Value4': 8, 'Value5': 10}, {'Channel_No':9, 'Value1': 2, 'Value2': 1, 'Value3': 3, 'Value4': 4, 'Value5': 5}, {'Channel_No':10, 'Value1': 0, 'Value2': 0, 'Value3': 0, 'Value4': 0, 'Value5': 0}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

fig = plt.figure()
camera = Camera(fig)

for col in df.columns[1:]:
    plt.plot(df[col])
    camera.snap()
    
animation = camera.animate()
animation.save('animated.gif', writer = 'imagemagick')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  Is there a setting for animation speed?

Comment: Yes there is. You can use `animation = camera.animate(interval=200, blit=True)` and change the value `200` to the value you need.

Comment: Thank you.  I will try this as soon as I can.